# Encrypt Folder using TPM so that only my program can access key

Tags: tpm

I want to be able to encrypt a folder, then have my program only be able to decrypt the folder.  I understand that I may have to have my program run as its own user, but what I want to know is if there is already a TPM owner, would that owner have access to my stored key even if my program is the one that requested and stored that key?

I don't mind if the administrator would be able to delete the encrypted folder, but I do not want any user of the computer to be able to obtain the key and decrypt the contents.

Edit: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=F69zBgAAQBAJ&rdid=book-F69zBgAAQBAJ&rdot=1&source=gbs_vpt_read&pcampaignid=books_booksearch_viewport

So according to this text, this is a possible scenario, but you have to pass the TPM an authValue in order to operate on the entity.

But how would you store this authValue if your program is running in memory and this value can be deduced?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using TBS contexts in Windows.  More can be read here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725663(v=vs.85).aspx

These services are available to the following users and contain their own contexts:

Administrators, NT AUTHORITY\LocalService, and NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService